# how to replace existing serilog implementation with Azure App Insights

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, serilog, appinsights

I have an existing asp.net Web api project. this project is using Serilog for logging. Using OwinStartup it is configuring Serilog like this

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .CreateLogger();

        logger.Information("Api Startup");
```

and AppSettings has bunch of settings.

instance is also registered like this

```
        builder.RegisterInstance(logger).As<ILogger>().SingleInstance().PropertiesAutowired();
```

i there a way i can replace this serilog implementation with app insights or somehow use it together so all the logs goes inside app Insights and not in file system as configured right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the package `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights` and add AppInsights as a sink for Serilog

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo
    .ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.Active, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
    .CreateLogger();
```

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights